# Modifying an Array Passed as an Argument in Java

Tags: java, methods, encapsulation

Why does this work, displaying `array` in sorted order?:

```
Integer[] array={7,5,9,3,6,0,2,4};

MergeSort.mergeSort(array,0,7);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Specifically, why does passing `array` to a public static void method `mergeSort` end up modifying the array itself? I thought that Java protected from this. For example this code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int c=2;
    change(c);
    System.out.print(c);
  }
  public static void change(int c){
    c=4;
  }
```

returns 2 instead of 4. I am confused why Java allows you to modify an array passed as a parameter, but not an int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Java is pass by value, and when you pass an `Object` (and array is an `Object`) you pass the value of the reference to the `Object`. In contrast, a primitive has no reference so you just pass the value.

**Edit**

Similarly, you could have used the built in [`Arrays.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28Object[]%29) method to sort your array. Java arrays are not primitive types. In Java, the primitive wrapper types are immutable (like `String`). Consider,

```
private static void change(String in) {
    in = in + " World"; // <-- modifies in here, can't change caller's reference.
}

private static void change(StringBuilder in) {
    in.append(" World"); // <-- uses reference from caller.
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "Hello";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
    change(str);
    change(sb);
    System.out.println("one: " + str);
    System.out.println("two: " + sb);
}
```

Comment: Is this answer really complete ? The erroneous answer of hexafraction shows that there is a few more to say about this, because just replacing c by an array would not change anything

Comment: @Dici why Java allows you to modify an array passed as a parameter, but not an int? Because an `int` is a primitive. And the wrapper types are immutable.

Comment: Yep, but not as hexafraction suggests it. If it is an object, a side-effects method must be called on it, if it is an array, we have to directly assign a value to `a[i]`. `myParameter = someNewValue;` has no effect, I think it is important to explain here.

Answer (score 0):

When using an array, taken as a parameter or not, consider that `arr[i]` is a pointer to some location of the memory. Then, when receiving an array as a parameter, you have a new reference pointing to the same array object. That means that in your method, instructions such as :

```
myParameterArray = new int[5];
```

won't modify the input array, because you are just changing the value of a reference, not the value pointed by it. Nevertheless, instructions such as :

```
myParameterArray[i] = 5;
```

will directly modify your input array. That is how methods like `Arrays.sort` work.